# BI Publisher SQL vs SQL Developer - Varchar Date Field

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I am able to get the following code to work on SQL Developer, but when I run it in BI Publisher I get ORA-1722: invalid number

```
SELECT NVL(:PM_date_from,TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE -1,'yymm')||'01','yymmdd')) from_date_batch
                          ,NVL(:PM_date_to,SYSDATE -1) to_date_batch
                      FROM DUAL
                     WHERE :PM_mode = 'B'
                     UNION ALL
                    SELECT NVL(:PM_date_from,TO_CHAR('1901-01-01','YYYY-MM-dd')) from_date_batch
                          ,NVL(:PM_date_to,TO_CHAR('2036-01-01','YYYY-MM-dd')) to_date_batch
                      FROM DUAL
                     WHERE :PM_mode = 'A'
```

Comment: You've got implicit casts in there. The top union has dates and the bottom union has chars. Pick one, not both.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe SQL developer is making some assumptions, but in the second part of this sql, you will require a to_date function, instead of to_char.

Try this:

```
SELECT NVL(:PM_date_from,TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE -1,'yymm')||'01','yymmdd')) from_date_batch
                          ,NVL(:PM_date_to,SYSDATE -1) to_date_batch
                      FROM DUAL
                     WHERE :PM_mode = 'B'
                     UNION ALL
                    SELECT NVL(:PM_date_from,TO_DATE('1901-01-01','YYYY-MM-dd')) from_date_batch
                          ,NVL(:PM_date_to,TO_DATE('2036-01-01','YYYY-MM-dd')) to_date_batch
                      FROM DUAL
                     WHERE :PM_mode = 'A'
```